# Observe an ObservableList using TableView.getItems()?

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

This is JavaFX.

I had a TableView named tableView whose items is a non-empty ObservableList called dataList. The TableView had contained dataList by calling tableView.setItems(dataList);
Then, I added a ListChangeListener to tableView.getItems() called listChangeListener. The call was tableView.getItems().addListener(listChangeListener);

```
tableView.setItems(dataList);
tableView.getItems().addListener(listChangeListener);
```

Now, whenever dataList is changed, I notice that listChangeListener doesn't get called. However, tableView's contents change into the contents of dataList. Why is this so? How can I detect the change using only the variables inside tableView or the tableView itself?

Notes:

I don't want to call dataList.addListener(listChangeListener) because I want to be able to call tableView.setItems(anotherDataList); at some point.

I also tried using itemsProperty().addListener(aDifferentListener); but there arose another problem wherein the listener also doesn't get called.

Comment: refresh the table view in dataList.If add any new data from dataList automatically your table view is update.

Comment: Hi Reegan, did you mean I should refresh the table view in dataList so that the content of the table updates? Anyway, the TableView gets updated alright already, but the TableView's listener doesn't get called.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the following code:

```
tableView.getItems().addListener(new ListChangeListener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onChanged(
                    ListChangeListener.Change<? extends String> arg0) {
                System.out.println("Changed!!");

            }
        });
```

And the change listener was called...
Can you post your code so that we can take a look at it?

Comment: Hi Magcus, here's the code I'm referring to: dataList = new ArrayList(); dataList.add("1"); //As you'll notice the ListChangeListener will not be called on the invocation of datalist.add("1"); Thank you by the way.

Comment: Well, it might not be a bad idea to use directly the observable list of the tableView, and add the item there:
tableView.getItems().add("1");

Comment: I'll check it out then try to reply about the outcome. Thanks.

Comment: It worked in my case to always use TableView.getItems() instead of having dataList. Thank you.